# angular ui router disable for some links

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-router

i would like to use the bootstrap accordion in my angular-application.
I'm using the angular ui-router for Routing through the sites.

Now I'm facing a problem that the accordion needs an

```
<a href="#CollapseOne"> Tag.
```

The problem is that the ui-router "thinks" it has to do something and tries to navigate to "#CollapseOne".

How can I stop ui-routing on some ?

Comment: can you please post some more code or provide a plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$urlRouterProvider.when()` with a do nothing handler function to stop routing for some URLs

```
$urlRouterProvider.when("/CollapseOne", function() {
  //do nothing
});
```

Alternatively simply replace `href` with `data-target` which will fix your problem

```
<a data-target="#CollapseOne" data-toggle="collapse">Tag</a>.
```

Comment: thank you. data-target is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Use Angular UI Bootstrap. You can find Accordion here: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/